# VisualStateManager does not work inside Panorama control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visualstatemanager, panorama-control

I am trying to use VisualStateManager inside a Panorama control but it is not working.

XAML

```
<phone:Panorama x:Name="Pano">
    <phone:PanoramaItem x:Name="PanoItem">

        <StackPanel x:Name="Stack">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.600"
                                             To="90"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationY"
                                             Storyboard.TargetName="plane"
                                             d:IsOptimized="True">
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <Button Content="some text"
                    x:Name="ToFade">
                <Button.Projection>
                    <PlaneProjection x:Name="plane" />
                </Button.Projection>
            </Button>
            <Button Content="Change"
                    Click="Button_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
    </phone:PanoramaItem>
</phone:Panorama>
```

Code behind

```
    private void Button_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e ) {
        var result = VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Normal", true);
    }
```

The strange part is that if I take the `<StackPanel>` off of `<Panorama>` the state change works like a charm.

This Works:

```
<!--<phone:Panorama x:Name="Pano">
    <phone:PanoramaItem x:Name="PanoItem">-->

        <StackPanel x:Name="Stack">
```

... rest same code as above ...

```
        </StackPanel>
    <!--</phone:PanoramaItem>
</phone:Panorama>-->
```

I have tried passing other controls to the `VisualStateManager.GoToState()` like `this`, `this.Pano`, `this.PanoItem` but without success. Can someone explain what is wrong? and Why?